# Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, input

I'm trying to get this program to work but no dice. I think it's perfect but something is missing. It's supposed to display the prices of tickets based on the amount of tickets and the type of tickets purchased and then display the price and the total revenue of all tickets.

```
namespace stadiumApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void calculateRevenue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //assigns input to saved memory 
                string inputA="";
                string inputB ="";
                string inputC ="";

                double ticketsPurchasedB = double.Parse(inputB);
                double ticketsPurchasedA = double.Parse(inputA);
                double ticketsPurchasedC = double.Parse(inputC);

               //price of each ticket grade
                double priceA = 15;
                double priceB = 12;
                double priceC = 9;

                //calculations for each class
                double calcOutputA = priceA * ticketsPurchasedA ;
                string outputA = calcOutputA.ToString();

            double calcOutputB = priceB * ticketsPurchasedB;
            string outputB = calcOutputB.ToString();

            double calcOutputC = priceC * ticketsPurchasedC;
            string outputC = calcOutputC.ToString();

           //calculations for total revenue
         double totalLabelHolder = calcOutputA + calcOutputB + calcOutputC;
           //display total 
            string totalLabel = totalLabelHolder.ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This problem statement isn't very specific. Please include what error you are getting, what *exactly* isn't working, etc.

Comment: With some code only all we can say is "Yup, works as written". Cut it down to a minimal example, explain what you want/expect, what you get, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make textboxes on your form and use their values instead of:

```
string inputA="";
string inputB ="";
string inputC ="";
```

Every one of these lines will throw an error (because you can't parse an empty string to a double):

```
double ticketsPurchasedB = double.Parse(inputB);
double ticketsPurchasedA = double.Parse(inputA);
double ticketsPurchasedC = double.Parse(inputC);
```